# If drop down not selected show error message

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

How to show error message if dropdown option not picked. when click next and message should appear please see the below picture.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it on frontend then why you didn't validate the form before submit here is an example

```
<select id="select-gender" form="myForm" name="radios">
  <option id="opt-default" form="myForm" value="" selected> Please Select </option>
  <option id="sexmale" name="radios" value="Male" form="myForm"> Male </option>
  <option id="sexfemale" name="radios" value="Female" form="myForm"> Female </option>
</select>


<button onclick="validateForm()">Submit</button>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
</form>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
//Error Msg for input field
function validateForm() {

  let gender = document.forms["myForm"]["radios"].value;

  if (gender == "") {

    //You can use soft messenging using Jquery as well
    alert("Please select your Gender");
    return false;

  }
}
```

Comment: How to get the ID of the button because it a theme button secondly it not radio buttons @Syed

Comment: For instance cannot you get it by inspect ?